# Chage focus javaw window in TestComplete

Tags: window, focus, testcomplete, switching

I have a java application called App 1.4 () (which I have no access to the code) that, while running up another java application App2 (and a host of other applications). The application App2 is shot from within the App and you can not run your jar. I wonder how do I put App2 in focus and click a button on it.
I did the following code:

```
setPropertieWithClickOnBoxApp2 function ()
{
  Aliases.Explorer.wndShell_TrayWnd.ReBarWindow32.MSTaskSwWClass.ToolbarWindow32.CheckItem ("App2", true, false);
  Aliases.javaw1.frame01.RootPane.null_layeredPane.null_contentPane.Panel.Panel.Panel.RadioButton.ClickButton();
}
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
It is necessary to set the next context into the previous context routine code.